# Data filter QR scan

Tags: string, google-sheets, split, datatable, digits

I'm trying to get the following. I have a string of data 100 digits or 200 that I need to split up.

So in each cell there will be 10 digits, then an enter, then the 10 next digits, and so on.

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1&"","(?s)(.{10})","$1"&TEKEN(127)),"'","''"),TEKEN(127))
```

Comment: What tool/language are you using? That is not mentioned in the question, or in the tags. Is this for an Excel spreadsheet? Or maybe a Google Sheet? Or something else? Also, what is `TEKEN()`? You should add the most relevant _specific_ technology tags so that your question will be seen by the relevant community experts.

Comment: You can also take the [tour], read [ask] and browse the content in the [help] for more guidance.